# Gradle KMM custom attribute doesn't get propagated to project's KMM dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

Assume I have 3 gradle projects with the following paths and file contents:

`:sub1` is a KMM project:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

val customAttribute = Attribute.of("custom", String::class.java)

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    jvm {
        attributes {
            attribute(customAttribute, "normal")
        }
    }
    jvm("custom") {
        attributes {
            attribute(customAttribute, "customValue")
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
    }
}
```

`:sub2` is a KMM project that depends on `:sub1`:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

val customAttribute = Attribute.of("custom", String::class.java)

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    jvm {
        attributes {
            attribute(customAttribute, "normal")
        }
    }
    jvm("custom") {
        attributes {
            attribute(customAttribute, "customValue")
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":sub1"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`:parent` which is a JVM project that depends on `:sub2`:

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

val customAttribute = Attribute.of("custom", String::class.java)

dependencies {
    api(project(":sub2")) {
        attributes {
            attribute(customAttribute, "customValue")
        }
    }
}
```

Building `:project` causes the following error:

```
   > Could not resolve project :sub1.
     Required by:
         project :project > project :sub2
      > The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :sub1
          - jvmApiElements
          - jvmRuntimeElements
          - customApiElements
          - customRuntimeElements
```

How do I make it so that the "customValue" of customAttribute declared in `:project` propagates down to the project `:sub1` from `:sub2`, instead of only going down to `:sub2`, so that the "custom" JVM target is chosen?

I have tried to set a Gradle project property during the configuration step, but I can't seem to find a way to guarantee project configuration order, so I can't reliably use properties either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to error message in project `:sub2` Gradle can't choose between `jvm` and `jvm("custom")` for `:sub1`.

Targets should be marked on both the library and consumer sides with a custom attribute, which Gradle uses during dependency resolution.

So in project `:sub2` you either need to specify variant attribute for `:sub1` project or move dependency from common source. For example:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":sub1")) {
                    attributes {
                        attribute(customAttribute, "normal")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val customMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":sub1")) {
                    attributes {
                        attribute(customAttribute, "customValue")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Kotlin Multiplatform documentations for several targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-set-up-targets.html#distinguish-several-targets-for-one-platform)

Comment: Moving the dependencies from the common target to the other ones will cause project ":sub1"'s common source to not be available to ":sub2" and any other parent projects.

When you mean "specify variant attribute", do you mean just setting the attribute?

Comment: Yes, you need to mark the targets on both the library and consumer sides with a custom attribute, which Gradle uses during dependency resolution. Why do you think common source won't be available? It will be.

Comment: So, when I do that, the IDE I'm using (Android Studio) cannot resolve the common source references in the parent projects. It seems if I build using gradle only, the build actually succeeds. I figured out that moving the dependencies with the attribute set to the targets, as you stated, but ALSO adding a "compileOnly(project(":sub1"))" to the common target in :sub2 fixes the unresolved references in the IDE.